# Oracle - Clause where in case when

Tags: oracle

all!
I want to know how wrote this code of SQL, I already trying but i get message error.
I wrote two way different this SQL. See you below

```
SELECT *
  FROM tabela
 WHERE coluna IN (CASE WHEN 1 = :parametro THEN 1 WHEN 0 = :parametro THEN (2, 3) END)
```

And

```
SELECT *
  FROM tabela
 WHERE (CASE WHEN 1 = :parametro THEN coluna = 1 WHEN 0 = :parametro THEN coluna <> 1 END)
```

I tried to run but it get error. Please! you help to tick or fix this code.

Thank a lot.

Regards,
Jeison Pereira

Comment: It's nonsense. `CASE WHEN` can return only a scalar value - not a colletion like `(10, 20)`. What exactly do you want to achieve? Look at funtion `LNNVL` maybe it does what you need.

Answer (score 1):

One option is

```
SELECT *
  FROM tabela
 WHERE  'OK' =
         CASE WHEN   1 = :parametro and coluna = 1 then 'OK'
              WHEN   0 = :parametro and coluna in (2, 3) THEN 'OK'
         END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without a `CASE`

```
SELECT *
  FROM tabela
 WHERE (:parametro = 1 AND coluna = 1)
    OR (:parametro = 0 AND coluna <> 1 )
```